# How to filter out JSON data via a particular field?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am a newbie here and learning JS and JSON . 
Well, I have the JSON data as :

```
   {
      "month":"november",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":50,
      "name":"Pike Place Roast Brewed Coffee Verismo Pods",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":5,
      "roast":"medium",
      "type":"regular"
   },
   {
      "month":"august",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":40,
      "name":"Starbucks VIA Ready Brew French Roast",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":548,
      "roast":"blonde",
      "type":"decaffinated"
   },
   {
      "month":"november",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":50,
      "name":"Starbucks Caffé Verona Blend, Whole Bean",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":5,
      "roast":"medium",
      "type":"regular"
   },
   {
      "month":"asia-pacific",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":20,
      "name":"Starbucks Caffè Verona K-Cup Pods",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":3,
      "roast":"dark",
      "type":"regular"
   },
   {
      "month":"august",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":40,
      "name":"Milk Verismo Pods",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":233,
      "roast":"blonde",
      "type":"decaffinated"
   },
   {
      "month":"november",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":50,
      "name":"Starbucks VIA Ready Brew Decaf Italian Roast",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":5,
      "roast":"medium",
      "type":"regular"
   },
   {
      "month":"august",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":40,
      "name":"Guatemala Antigua Espresso Verismo Pods",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":587,
      "roast":"blonde",
      "type":"decaffinated"
   }
```

Now suppose I want to get all the data pertaining to the month (eg November) , how can I achieve this in Javascript ? 
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not JSON but I'm assuming it's a partial array.

```
var result = theArray.filter(function(value){
  return value.month === "November";   // or whatever you filter on
});

// result is now a filter array containing only month === 'November'
```

How does it work?

Filter loops over each item in the array (`value`). If you return true it's added to the new array. `false` ignores it (filtered out)

Comment: Thank you so much !
That helped me :)